# How to make a ZeroMatrix in 3D array C# (function)

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a function to make zeromatrix in 2D array, like this:

```
public double[][] ZeroMatrix(int rows, int cols)
{
    int i, j;
    double[][] m = new double[rows][];

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        m[i] = new double[cols];

        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            m[i][j] = 0;
    }

    return m;
}
```

How to make this matrix that will handled 3D arrays?
Maybe something like this:

```
public double[][][] ZeroMatrix(int rows, int cols, int etc)
{
    ...
    ...

    return m;
}
```

I tried some code, but always getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is better to use Multidimensional Arrays for this matter:

```
public double[,,] ZeroMatrix(int rows, int cols, int etc)
{
    double[,,] m = new double[rows, cols, etc];

    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
            for(int k = 0 ; k < etc ; k++)
                m[i , j , k] = 0;

    return m;
}
```

For more information about Multidimensional Arrays in C# read **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2yd9wwz4.aspx)**